# How to add an existing solution to a Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, version-control

I have a solution, which contains 7 projects.
I wanted to try out TFS (just to see how it works etc.), so I would like to add this existing solution to my TFS' DefaultCollection.

Is this possible without re-creating all the projects and adding their files?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. Create a Team Project to hold them
2. Create a workspace mapping between the team project and the current location of your code on disk
3. Go to Team Explorer, connect to your new project, double-click "Source Control"
4. Right-click the node for the new project and choose "Add to Source Control"

Comment: @lesderid: Edward Thomson's answer is probably better.

Comment: Well no because his solution is invalid when there's no team project set up yet.

Comment: How do I complete step #2? I created a new collection and I have a solution in my server folder. I would like to add that solution to the team project collection so I can edit and check in and someone else can edit and check it.

Comment: How do you create a team project?

Answer (score 38):

Sure, just right click on the solution in Solution Explorer and select "Add Solution to Source Control".

Comment: Is there a way to create a new team project and add the solution to source control all in one go? Currently we go to file new team project then add to source control, is this the fastest way?

Comment: Didn't work for me... Error. The team project folder $<folder_name> does not exist.

Comment: It automatically made a git source control. It's driving me insane

Answer (score 2):

For Team Foundation Service:

1. Go to your http://.visualstudio.com
2. Create a new Project via the website
3. Open your solution in Visual Studio 2017
4. Go to "Team Explorer" and **double click** the newly added project name from TFS (it is normally set in a gray color)
5. Go back to "Solution Explorer" and to right mouse click on the solution and select "Add to source control"
6. Right mouse click on the solution in "Solution Explorer" and select "Check in" for an initial check in to TFS

;-)

Answer (score 1):

This steps always work for me

1. Create new project at Azure Devops
2. Copy and paste the all the files onto another local directory in PC
3. Open the newly copied solution
4. Go to "File > Source Control > Advance > Change Source Control"
5. Unbind all the projects
6. Go to "File > Source Control > Advance > Workspaces", edit the existing workspace
7. Add a new "Working Folder" for the new repo
8. Open "Source Code Explorer", select the new source control
9. Drag the entire local directory folder onto the mapping
10. Check the excluded items, add in any wanted files
11. Check in
12. If source control binding is not there (no lock sign on the solution explorer), go to "File > Source Control > Advance > Change Source Control" to bind them