# how to checkin EAR to TFS from jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, tfsbuild

I have created a Jenkins Job which gets code from TFS and builds the EAR at jenkins default workspace (/opt/jenkins/lib/jobs/PROJECTNAME/workspace/dist).

After the EAR is built, I need to checkin this EAR to TFS, but I didn't see any option to checkin artifacts to TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [TFS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) in Jenkins to get the code from TFS. It will create a workspace when get the code. Settings as following:
[image]

And then, you can add an "Execute Windows batch command" build step to check in files to TFS after EAR build via [TF Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx).
[image]

Now you'll get the files been checked in:
[image]

In the command, I check in the folder generated by the build, you can also just add the items generated by the build.

Comment: I have crated similar script in gradle and executed its working fine. Yours also working fine thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

might be helpful.

Visit [how to add an existing solution to tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826546/how-to-add-an-existing-solution-to-a-team-foundation-server)

Another [add solution to TFS server](http://www.bandgap.cs.rice.edu/classes/comp410/resources/Using%20TFS/How%20to%20add%20an%20existing%20solution%20to%20an%20existing%20TFS%20project.aspx)